# Retrieving articles based on custom URL parameters

Tags: joomla

I'm a beginner using Joomla 1.5. I have a page which shows articles in a blog format.   My objective is to show/filter the articles per year (which isn't that many) based on user input. I'm planning to create a module on the right side, showing a dropdown box of the years, and retrieve the results by passing the year parameter as part of the URL

Ex.

http://sample.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=39&Itemid=24&year=2011

What is the best, simplest way of passing and processing additional parameters to com_content via URL?  Can I do so using extensions such as K2 and flexicontent?  If not, can someone advise me what code to add and where, in com_content?  If I have to extend com_content itself, can someone guide me how to or point some useful articles?

Appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if K2 or flexicontent offer this option, but com_content appears NOT to have this feature.

I would just build a module, create a query and use the table **jos_content**, select only the fields that you need  (like title) and check the field *created* to be in the year you need.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that com_content cannot do this inherently. Can you detail your suggestion a bit further?  My initial take is that I have to create a "virtual" page to put that module (retrieving the contents) via {loadposition module}. My apprehension is that I have to format the module content to match the layout and formatting of the com_content.  Would this be the arduous but necessary road I have to take?

Comment: With a module you do all the formatting on the spot (by using a module I assume you don't need anything but a list of articles with links on them).

If you need more than this (like all the functionality of com_content), just make a copy of the component and mantian it.

If any case  do take a look at what K2 and flexicontent have, they may solve your problem.